# Calling a function on a component from the controller

Tags: ember.js

I like your opinion on this pattern. I wanted to be able to call focus function on a component from my controller, the way I implemented it was a reference to of itself by an action defined on the controller then call the method on it. It works fine just wondering if some sort anti-pattern I should stay away from?

```
{{x-input bindingAction=(action "bindInput")}}

<button {{action "focusOnInput">Focus on input</button>

 // x-input.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  init() {
    this._super();
    if (!Ember.isNone(this.get('bindingAction')) {
     this.get('bindingAction')(this)
    }   
  }

  focus() {
    // focus on component.
  }

});


// controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

actions: {

    bindInput(input) {
       this.set('input', input);    
    }

    focusOnInput() {
       this.get('input').focus();       
    }

}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Calling functions on a component from controller is anti-pattern. Always follow Data Down and Actions Up strategy.
Required Data should be passed to components, and Component should communicate changes through by sending actions.

Below some of the articles to understand it better,
- https://emberigniter.com/getting-started-ember-cli-data-down-actions-up-tutorial/
- https://dockyard.com/blog/2015/10/14/best-practices-data-down-actions-up
- http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/data-down-actions-up/
- https://blog.embermap.com/passing-data-around-your-ember-application-c4fe1e06e90

---

If you still want to do it, then I will go with this options, 
Here is the [twiddle demonstrating](https://ember-twiddle.com/560b8fb904bcca1556dc5d48731bff1e?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs)

controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  componentRef:null,
  actions:{
    registerComponent(componentRef){
      this.set('componentRef',componentRef);
    },
    deregisterComponent(){
      this.set('componentRef',null);
    },
    callComponentMethod(){
        this.get('componentRef').sayHi();
      }
  }
});
```

components/my-component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement(){
    this.get('registerComponent')(this);
  },
  willDestroyElement(){
    this.get('deregisterComponent')();
    this._super(...argument);    
  },
  sayHi(){
   alert(' Hi from component');
  }

});
```

application.hbs

```
<h1 {{action 'callComponentMethod'}}>Welcome to {{appName}}</h1>
<br>
{{my-component registerComponent=(action 'registerComponent') deregisterComponent=(action 'deregisterComponent')}}
{{outlet}}
```

Comment: Yes I understand the pattern DDAU pattern, but in this case how else would do this?

Comment: You can achieve your use case using the DDAU., do you have any specific use case for this ?. Sorry I dont understand why the controller should call component on element focus ?

Comment: Yes when basically when we have modal window open and we close it we want to focus on a specific field for accessibility.

Comment: If you still want to do it,Then you need to keep the reference of the rendered component in the controller. You can achieve this, by sending one action controller to component and on which component will set `this` reference on `didInsertElement` and will call deRegister by calling it on the `willDestroyElement` . here is the twiddle demonstrating.https://ember-twiddle.com/560b8fb904bcca1556dc5d48731bff1e?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs